# Product card is not proper

Tags: css

I want to display the discount tag over the image like this but i got like in below image

Discount tag displayed above the image

I don't want to hide the color with white as i commanded 3rd line in my css file.Is any other way to achieve this?

Moreover I want to display products with proper looking. But it looks not good the  product card height differs depend on the content i add. I'm using mdBootstrap to style.

Can Anyone help me out?

My code:

```css
.shape {
  border-color: #E87E0E;
  /* border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) #E87E0E rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0); */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 70px 40px 0;
  float: right;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.shape-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  right: -40px;
  top: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.card-product .img-wrap {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-product .img-wrap img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <figure class="card card-product">
    <div class="discount">
      <div class="shape">
        <span class="shape-text">17% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=assets/Image/{{ product.Image }}">
    </div>
    <figcaption class="info-wrap">
      <h4 class="title">{{product.ProductName}}</h4>
      <div class="rating-wrap">
        <div class="label-rating">132 reviews</div>
        <div class="label-rating">154 orders </div>
      </div>
    </figcaption>
    <div class="bottom-wrap">
      <div class="price-wrap h5">
        <span class="price-new">Rs.{{product.Price}}  </span>
        <del class="price-old">Rs.1980</del>
      </div>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the shape to be on top of the image you have to remove it from the document flow with `position:absolute;` , `float` will not help you here.

then adjust your `z-index` to be a higher number try 999 and adjust the `position:absolute` for the .shape and add a `position:relative` to the .discount

```css
.discount{
position:relative;
}
.shape {
  border-color: #E87E0E;
  /* border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) #E87E0E rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0); */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 70px 40px 0;
  height: 20px; 
  width:0;
  /* here is the stuff you should add */
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}

.shape-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  right: -40px;
  top: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.card-product .img-wrap {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-product .img-wrap img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <figure class="card card-product">
    <div class="discount">
      <div class="shape">
        <span class="shape-text">17% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/550x250?text=assets/Image/{{ product.Image }}">
    </div>
    <figcaption class="info-wrap">
      <h4 class="title">{{product.ProductName}}</h4>
      <div class="rating-wrap">
        <div class="label-rating">132 reviews</div>
        <div class="label-rating">154 orders </div>
      </div>
    </figcaption>
    <div class="bottom-wrap">
      <div class="price-wrap h5">
        <span class="price-new">Rs.{{product.Price}}  </span>
        <del class="price-old">Rs.1980</del>
      </div>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about the height alignment of image?

Comment: what is the question? do you want to move the image or the shape? I added a width:100% to the image that may be what you are wanting

Comment: No,as i mentioned above the product card size changes according to the contents inside it(like the product name). What should i do if i want to display all the cards with same height along with all contents?

Comment: set a `min-height` or a fixed `height` and either hide the overflow or truncate it with a "read more" link or something

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try checking with JS fiddle, try with removing `border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;`

Comment: What's the purpose of removing it?